# URLError: urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pandas

I was perfectly able to use pandas `read_csv` for reading files in Windows. However I cannot figure out how to set local path in Ubuntu?

If I do this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'file://home/gosper/Desktop/test.csv')
```

... it throws the error: `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: How about just `/home/gosper/Desktop/test.csv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work for Windows's and UNIX's Desktop folder:

```
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser('~') + '/Desktop/test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for both Unix and Windows Systems.

```
import os

desktop = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(desktop, 'test.csv'))
```

For Python3.5 + we can use this also.

```
import pathlib
import os
desktop = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Desktop'
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(desktop, 'test.csv'))
```